# Unable to set parameter values from OpenAPI examples when importing spec into Postman

Tags: postman, openapi

I'm currently trying to import an OpenAPI spec into Postman to generate a collection. I am using OpenAPI 3.0 and using Postman v7.25.0. I'm having an issue where I'm trying to automatically have the `Value` of one of my path parameters in Postman automatically set based on an example that I define in the spec. Here's a little snippet (YAML) of how I've implemented an example for one of my parameters:

```
...
parameters:
  - name: id
    in: path
    required: true
    schema:
      type: string
      example: TEST_VALUE
    description: Generic description for ID
...
```

It *does* look like I'm adding the example value to the correct spot according to [the OpenAPI 3.0 spec](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/#parameters). Additionally, it *does* appear that Postman supports this functionality -- there's an option when I import the spec that says this:

> **Request parameter generation**
>
> Select whether to generate the request parameters based on the schema or the example in the schema.

I am making sure to set that option's value to `Example` rather than the default value of `Schema`. However, once I generate the collection and open up this specific request with the examples, the value of the parameter is just `<string>` rather than the expected value of `TEST_VALUE`. Every other part of the request generates correctly according to my spec, but it's just the parameter values that I'm having a tough time to get mapped to my example values.

Greatly appreciate any help I can get on this. Thanks!

Comment: If you add the `example` alongside schema (i.e. as a parameter attribute) rather than inside `schema`, does it work?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Helen , I just tried your suggestion and unfortunately it still puts the value as `<string>`.